# Pushing changes to remote master after rebasing local branch

Tags: git

Okay, I obviously have a little problem here understanding what I have to do in order to get this right.

I have pushed a lot of commits to the remote master which I'd like to squash now. In order to do so I've started a `git rebase -i HEAD~20` session and used `squash` in order to *squash* some commits into one.

After some conflicts which I was able to resolve I was left with a "shortened" version of my local branch - but at this point I don't know how to get this onto the remote branch.

If I run `git status` it will tell me that the local and master branch differ in 1 and 11 commits.

If I'd run `git pull` at this point the whole `rebase` action gets undone and I am back to where I started.

So essentially I went from something like:

```
a                   b
o-->o-->o-->o-->o-->o
     \         /
      o-->o-->o
```

to

```
a   b
o-->o
```

but only *locally*. Can I squash the commits on the remote if I push local?

Comment: @kaitoy whops, sorry. it's quite early for me - changed that :D

Comment: Typically, the normal git workflows do not allow you to rewrite history in the remote (what your'e doing here is rewrtiting history, removing those 11 commits from the master branch).

If you are the only one working with that remote branch, you can do `git push -f` if you have the permissions for that. However, you should not do that if there are others users who are also working based on the same remote branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some confusion in the terms you use.
There is such thing is 'push local'. The `push` action is from your local to the remote.

So, if you pushed your changes, they are shared in the remote repository.

Once those changes are shared, it is not recommended to squash them. Since anyone who already `pulled` your changes will have problems.

It is possible though.
You need to force push your changes.

`git push -f`

Comment: Oh, okay. Well it's for a pull request on github - so nobody will have pulled my changes yet besides me. So this shouldn't break anything I guess?

Comment: It shouldn't break anything. It does rewrite the history.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just do a force push by `git push -f`.